# CreateProcess ошибка 1812: CreateProcessW - The specified image file did not contain a resource section

Tags: c++, c

Есть код создания процесса, на виртуальных машинах и на моём pc он отрабатывает корректно, подключаюсь по RDP к клиенту, передаю файл, запускаю -

> [Error 1812] CreateProcessW - The specified image file did not contain a resource section.

Код по сути

```
STARTUPINFOW si = {0};
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};
si.cb = sizeof(si);
CreateProcessW(0, szCmdLine, 0, 0, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
```

При чём это не зависит от версии ОС, и на всех машинах к которым имею доступ физически - всё работает.

Comment: Как был получен код и сообщение об ошибке? В приведенном коде ничего такого нет. Добавьте после CreateProcess что-то типа printf ("0x%X\n", GetLastError()); и покажите его вывод.

Comment: С помощью GetLastError и FormatMessage сразу же после CreateProcessW.

Comment: Мистика... Приведите больше кода, особенно интересует проверка успешности CreateProcess. EXE у вас обычный, с нативным кодом? Или какое-нибудь .NET?

Comment: Вот вот... мистика... а больше кода и нет, это начало функции. С нативным кодом, запускал даже под отладчиком - сразу после CreateProcessW пауза в пару секунд и ошибка, а проверка - на ненулевое значение.

Comment: Кстати да, на 3 машинах из 10 код сегодня заработал.

Comment: Вообще интересно что конкретно означает эта ошибка.

Comment: Забыл сказать - стартуется функция из отдельного потока, поток создаётся с помощью _beginthreadex

Comment: Ошибка связана с секцией ресурсов, но файлы без нее вполне могут запускаться.